# Why set setxkbdmap work differently from the GUI keyboard map switcher (super-space)?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

This is a follow-up to an earlier question: [Reassigning modifier keys with xkb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187610/reassigning-modifier-keys-with-xkb). The keyboard map given in that question works with setxkbmap, but when the map is selected through the GUI (having added the map to evdev.xml).

I've since discovered the following, which is independent of that map: Switching with setxkbmap seems to be different to switching with the GUI, even for that standard maps included. Try the following

```
 Use GUI to switch to US (typically done with super-space or via top bar)
 press shift-3 --> #
 Use GUI to switch to United Kingdom
 press shift-3 --> £
 Terminal> setxkbmap us
 press shift-3 --> #
 use GUI to switch to United Kingdom
 press shift-3 still gives #
```

Any ideas what's happening here?

(Possibly related question: [xkbmap works with setxkbmap, but not in GUI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187790/xkbmap-works-with-setxkbmap-but-not-in-gui))

Comment: What is written on you physical key (# or £)? In other words, what do you want?

Comment: To answer your question: I've got a keyboard layout here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187610/reassigning-modifier-keys-with-xkb/1187783#1187783 (see post above) that works with setxkbdmap but not the GUI. I want to get it going on the GUI. That led me to discover this problem. I have a UK keyboard, so the key is labled 3/£, but I'd like to be able to switch seamlessly between US and UK keyboards. Does that help?